# select merged column value sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

There is 2 tables Bookings and BookingNote

Table Bookings contains BookingId and other booking related columns.

Whenever there is an update to the booking, A note is added to the BookingNote Table.

BookingNote table example:

| BookingId | Note |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Booking Created |
| 123 | User Details Updated |
| 123 | Booking Cancelled |

```
Select B.BookingId ,
            Case 
            When N.Note = 'Booking Created'  Then N.Note 
            When N.Note = 'Booking Cancelled' Then N.Note 
    End
    
    
    From    Bookings as B
        Join    Notes as N
     On B.BookingId = N.BookingId
        Where   N.Note = 'Booking Created'
        Or  N.Note = 'Booking Cancelled'
```

Result

| BookingId | Note |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Booking Cancelled |
| 123 | Booking Created |

How can I get a merged note when there is a  'Booking Created' and 'Booking Cancelled' for a BookingId so that I can get a result like this

| BookingId | Note |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Booking Cancelled , Booking Created |

Comment: Try adding a function that when a booking is cancelled, then created, the two previous notes are deleted, and a new note with both appears. You might have to do this manually.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using STRING_AGG:

```
SELECT BookingId, STRING_AGG (Note,', ') FROM BookingNote group by BookingId;
```

This works by specifying the common identifier in the table (in this case, BookingId), and then STRING_AGG joins all text common to that identifier - in this case separated by a comma as specified.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database you are using, you can use string aggregation and group by BookingID.
E.g. if you are using MSSQL (T-SQL):

```
Select B.BookingId ,
            STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),
            Case 
            When N.Note = 'Booking Created'  Then N.Note 
            When N.Note = 'Booking Cancelled' Then N.Note
            End , ',')  
    From    Bookings as B
        Join    Notes as N
     On B.BookingId = N.BookingId
        Where   N.Note = 'Booking Created'
        Or  N.Note = 'Booking Cancelled'
    GROUP BY B.BookingId
```